# MySQL fails to start in XAMPP due to mysqld.exe error

Tags: mysql, xampp

Everything was working fine. I've worked with xampp for about 4 years now and I've never encountered such problem. Tried to start MySQL from XAMPP and it failed. upon looking at the error log, I have deducted that one of the folders are corrupted and if so, how do I fix it?

mysql_error.log (part of it):

```
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=38825021
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.6 started; log sequence number 38825030; transaction id 21030
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-01-19 11:56:21 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-01-19 20:37:41 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: Aria engine: starting recovery
recovered pages: 0% 17%
2020-01-19 20:37:41 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Index for table '.\mysql\db' is corrupt; try to repair it

***WARNING: .\mysql\db could not be opened: Error: 126
 27% 39% 52% 62% 73% 86% 96% 100% (0.0 seconds); tables to flush: 1 0 (0.0 seconds); 
2020-01-19 20:37:41 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: Aria engine: recovery done
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-01-19 20:37:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-01-19 20:37:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-01-19 20:37:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813392/mysql-fails-to-start-in-xampp-due-to-mysqld-exe-error

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, one index is corrupt.

- Launch your server first in recovery mode. Add `innodb_force_recovery=1` to your `my.cnf`.  In case your server doesn’t start, you may increase this number from 1 to 6, check MySQL manual to see what the differences are (dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)
- Run `mysqlcheck -c` on all of the relevant tables to find out which ones had index corruption
- Use `mysqlcheck --optimize` from command line to rebuid the table that have corrupt indexes

Otherwise they to rebuild the table, some times a dump and import will help.  check this section of the docs with alternative ideas https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! I dont have this util added to my PATH. Where can I find it?

Comment: Depends on the operating system and your xampp. But it should be in the bin folder of mysql. The same folder as your mysql.exe

Comment: Yep, found it. I'm trying to run it (syntax: mysqlcheck.exe -c db_name table_name) but it throws a connection error. So, i cannot start the MySQL server, how do I check the tables?

Comment: Launch your server first in recovery mode. Add innodb_force_recovery=1 to your my.cnf .In case your server doesn’t want to come back, you may further increase this number from 1 to 6, check MySQL manual to see what the differences are, but 1 should work.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html